# A copy of one depot path into two different workspace locations

Tags: teamcity, perforce, teamcity-7.0

We have a Perforce depot path called "Shared" with a number of subfolders, all just containing zero-length dummy files, no real source files, to create a specific folder structure in the workspace. We want to have this same folder structure a second time, this time called "Artifacts".

Is there a way to map one depot path into two workspace locations using Perforce?

UPDATE: Since there is no way to copy one depot path into two workspace locations using Perforce, I had to go for some other solution. This is a good thing because having a shadow copy of a depot path has a smell anyway. Now I introduced a "Pre build" step resetting all archive flags in the Shared folder. And I've added a "Post build" step xcopiing all files with archive flag set into an Artifacts folder. That's exactly meeting my requirements without having to solve the above question.

Thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: How do you use the Shared depot? Is it a template for creating a new project?

Comment: No, it's rather a location to store compiled assemblies to, which are used by subsequent builds. Our VS2010 project is devided into a number of solutions. Assemblies created by eralier solutions are copied into the Shared folder structure and referenced by file reference from subsequent projects.

Comment: Depending on what sort of system you're on, this might be a reasonable use of symbolic links. In your "Artifacts" folder, create symbolic links to your "Shared" folder.

Comment: I'm on Windows. And well, that would imply that I'd have an Artifacts folder with the same structure. Obviously, I could create a copy of the Shared depot folder in Perforce but I wanted to avoid the redundancy.

Comment: How would you use the shared and artifacts folders? e.g. you need to check-out files, submit new versions of assemblies etc.

Comment: That's the tough part to explain: We have a complex product built from various solutions, let's say A, B, and C. At the moment, all solutions are built in one build process. Since C uses assemblies from B and A, and B uses assemblies built by A, all put their assemblies to Shared, where the subsequent solutions reference them from.

Comment: ... Now we are migrating to TeamCity. We want to built A, B, and C separately to save the time used to build A and B even if only C has changed. Therefor, I have to declare the dependency assemblies as artifacts. I could list all the artifacts of A in Shared, all the artifacts of B and so on. But I would prefer to have an Artifacts folder structure similar to Shared for each solution. This way, I could declare Artifacts/**/*.dll to collect all newly built assemblies during a single solution build.

Comment: There are tools to support symlinks on windows, sysinternals has had a tool for years http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768 in addition, if you have Win2k8 or Vista/Win7, you can use mklink http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Perforce mapping is 1:1.  Think about it.  If you were to edit a file in both locations, how should Perforce handle that?  It gets very complicated when a single file in the Perforce depot is represented by two locations in your workspace, and rather than deal with that complexity, they've decided not to allow it.

Now, I would actually have preferred to have a feature where you can have a readonly mapping to allow just what you need without breaking the underlying 1:1 SCM functionality, but that's probably taking Perforce too far in a direction they don't want to invest effort into.

By far my biggest gripe, however, is that Perforce will not give any errors if you map a location to two workspace locations.  It will simply ignore one of them (the second one, I think).  This leads to a lot of confusion and is pretty poor behaviour from Perforce for what is a fairly obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to map one depot path into two workspace locations using Perforce.